# Timing out while editing

Tags: system

I'm finding that that system is logging me out while editing a post very quickly. Is it possible to change the time period so that I have longer before it times out?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to EE 2.8 (and after 2.2 I think) there's a hidden config variable called `cp_session_ttl` that allows you to set the time in seconds after which a cp session will expire if there has been no user activity.  I *think* you can also set a value of `0` to have sessions not expire (untested).

As of 2.8 this is replaced by [`expire_session_on_browser_close`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#expire-session-on-browser-close)

You can set config variables in your `config.php` (which you can find at `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` unless you've moved things around).

Comment: Thinking about it, it's not just the logging out, when editing/creating a post if you take too long and click save nothing is saved so you lose what you've just done. Would this expire_session fix this too?

Comment: It should do - try it! Basically it increases the amount of time that EE waits from the last CP session activity activity it knows about (e.g you clicked something) til when it expires your session.